# adding onClick functionality to React to do list

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, onclick

I've created a to do list with React. I want to be able to mark tasks completed simply by clicking on them. I also want to be able to clear task that have been completed by clicking a button. These two functions are not working correctly with the code I have set up. When I click on an individual todo item to mark it complete, every single to do item on the list gets marked complete and thus, appears with a 'line-through.' When I then click the designated button to clear completed tasks, absolutely nothing happens. Can someone help me resolve these two issues?

code from App component:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      todos: [
        {
          task: "learn how to fly drone",
          id: Date.now(),
          completed: false
        }, 
        {
          task: "learn React class components",
          id: Date.now(),
          completed: false
        },
        {
          task: "practice editing videos",
          id: Date.now(),
          completed: false
        },
        {
          task: "read Ten Years A Nomad",
          id: Date.now(),
          completed: false
        }
    ],
      todo: ''
    }
  }

  inputChangeHandler = event => {
    this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value})
  }

  addTask = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let newTask = {
      task: this.state.todo,
      id: Date.now(),
      completed: false
    };
    this.setState({
      todos: [...this.state.todos, newTask],
      todo: ''
    })
  }

  toggleComplete = itemId => {
    const todos = this.state.todos.map(todo => {
      if (todo.id === itemId) {
        todo.completed = !todo.completed
      }
      return todo
    });
    this.setState({todos, todo: ''})
  }

  clearCompleted = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    return this.state.todos.filter(item => !item.completed)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h2>Welcome to your Todo App!</h2>
        <TodoList 
          todos={this.state.todos} 
          toggleComplete={this.toggleComplete} />
        <TodoForm todos={this.state.todos} value={this.state.todo} inputChangeHandler={this.inputChangeHandler} addTask={this.addTask} clearCompleted={this.clearCompleted}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

TodoList:

```
const TodoList = props => {
    return (
        <div>
            {props.todos.map((todo, id) => (
                <Todo 
                    todo={todo} 
                    key={id} 
                    toggleComplete={props.toggleComplete} />
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}

export default TodoList;
```

Todo:

```
const Todo = props => {
    return (
        <div 
            key={props.todo.id}
            onClick={() => {
                props.toggleComplete(props.todo.id)
            }}>
            <p 
                style={{textDecoration: props.todo.completed ? 'line-through' : 'none'}}>
                {props.todo.task}
            </p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Todo;
```

TodoForm:

```
const TodoForm = props => {
    return (
        <form>
            <input 
                name="todo" 
                value={props.value} 
                type="text" 
                onChange={props.inputChangeHandler} 
                placeholder="Enter new task" />
            <button onClick={props.addTask}>Add Todo</button>
            <button onClick={props.clearCompleted}>Clear Completed</button>
        </form>
    )
}

export default TodoForm;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) The reason why every item is marked is because all objects within the `todos` state has the same id. Therefore, `toggleComplete()` will end up marking all objects within `todos` as `true`.

What you can do is to assign each object with a unique `id`, instead of assigning all `id` with the same `Date` object.

Here is an example:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    todos: [
      {
        task: "learn how to fly drone",
        id: 1,
        completed: false
      }, 
      {
        task: "learn React class components",
        id: 2,
        completed: false
      },
      {
        task: "practice editing videos",
        id: 3,
        completed: false
      },
      {
        task: "read Ten Years A Nomad",
        id: 4,
        completed: false
      }
  ],  
    todo: ''
  }
}
```

2) Next, `clearCompleted` is not calling `setState()`, hence, none of the tasks are cleared. I assume that you are trying to set `completed` as false? In that case, you can simply do set completed as `false` for all objects, and then update your state.

```
clearCompleted = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const todos = this.state.todos.map(todo => ({
    ...todo,
    completed: false,
  }));

  this.setState({
    todos,
  });
}
```

I have created a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-bird-wyosb?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) which fixes your issues.

Comment: Nice answer! I rushed my answer and overlooked that.. so obvious now... this should be selected as the accepted answer.

Comment: @MattOestreich glad to help! Feel free to check out the demo I have created. The problems should be solved :)

Comment: Thanks. I was able to fix the issues based on your answer. The clearCompleted function that you have up in the demo doesn't work just FYI. I got it to work by doing this...   clearCompleted = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const todos = this.state.todos.filter(item => !item.completed);
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      todos
    })
  }

Answer (score 1):

*Edit:*

[@wentjun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59495442/10431732) should be selected as the accepted answer.. I am going to leave this answer up though, as I still feel it provides value. To elaborate: I prefer to pass the index as it's a little faster then having to `map` over every single todo item just to find the one that was clicked. (Even if you used `this.state.todos.find(itm => itm.id === itemId`, passing the index is faster since you already know which item was clicked..

---

*Original Answer:*

I modified the `ToDo` component to pass the entire todo object in the click event, as well as passing the todo item index as well as the todo item within the `ToDoList` component. This way you can grab the index of the todo item that was clicked, to easily change the `completed` property on that specific todo item within state.

Even though I am not doing anything with the todo item object that is being passed via the click event, I recommend still passing the entire object, just in case - makes things more flexible. Open up your console to see the todo object that gets clicked.

*Edit:* I updated the `clearCompleted` to:

```
  clearCompleted = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let stateCopy = {...this.state};
    stateCopy.todos = stateCopy.todos.reduce((acc, cur) => 
      [...acc, {...cur, completed: false}], []
    );
    this.setState(stateCopy);
  };
```

I also modified your `setState` call within the click handler.. It is best practice to always make a copy of your state, modify the copy, then update state with the copy.

Demo:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      todos: [
        {
          task: "learn how to fly drone",
          id: Date.now(),
          completed: false
        },
        {
          task: "learn React class components",
          id: Date.now(),
          completed: false
        },
        {
          task: "practice editing videos",
          id: Date.now(),
          completed: false
        },
        {
          task: "read Ten Years A Nomad",
          id: Date.now(),
          completed: false
        }
      ],
      todo: ""
    };
  }

  inputChangeHandler = event => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

  addTask = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let newTask = {
      task: this.state.todo,
      id: Date.now(),
      completed: false
    };
    this.setState({
      todos: [...this.state.todos, newTask],
      todo: ""
    });
  };

  toggleComplete = (todoItem, todoItemIndex) => {
    let stateCopy = { ...this.state };
    let item = stateCopy.todos[todoItemIndex];
    item.completed = !item.completed;
    this.setState(stateCopy, () => 
      console.log(this.state.todos[todoItemIndex])
    );
  };

  clearCompleted = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let stateCopy = {...this.state};
    stateCopy.todos = stateCopy.todos.reduce((acc, cur) => 
      [...acc, {...cur, completed: false}], []
    );
    this.setState(stateCopy);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h2>Welcome to your Todo App!</h2>
        <TodoList
          todos={this.state.todos}
          toggleComplete={this.toggleComplete}
        />
        <TodoForm
          todos={this.state.todos}
          value={this.state.todo}
          inputChangeHandler={this.inputChangeHandler}
          addTask={this.addTask}
          clearCompleted={this.clearCompleted}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const TodoList = ({ todos, toggleComplete }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {todos && todos.map((todo, index) => (
        <Todo
          todo={todo} 
          key={index} 
          toggleComplete={() => toggleComplete(todo, index)} /* <<--- Pass the item and index to the handler function */ 
        />                                                   /* Even though we are not using the actual todo item     */
                                                             /* object, still not a bad idea to pass it thru          */ 
        
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const Todo = props => {
  return (
    <div 
      key={props.todo.id} 
      onClick={() => { props.toggleComplete(props.todo) }}> {/* Pass entire todo object, just in case you need it */}
      <p 
        style={{ 
          cursor: 'pointer',
          textDecoration: props.todo.completed ? "line-through" : "none" 
        }}>
        {props.todo.task}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};

const TodoForm = props => {
  return (
    <form>
      <input
        name="todo"
        value={props.value}
        type="text"
        onChange={props.inputChangeHandler}
        placeholder="Enter new task"
      />
      <button onClick={props.addTask}>Add Todo</button>
      <button onClick={props.clearCompleted}>Clear Completed</button>
    </form>
  );
};


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```